# Deserialize JSON with nested dictionary with DateTime as Key

Tags: c#, json, .net

I am trying to Deserialize JSON with nested dictionary, I cannot change the structure of JSON so i need to Deserialize it as it is -

JSON-

```
{
"session": {
    "UserID": 111,
    "SessionKey": "aaaa",
    "Culture": "en-CA"
},
"targetImports": {
    "SalesKPIName": "NetSales",
    "ImportType": 0,
    "ApportioningType": 0,
    "PeriodApportioningType": 0,
    "specificApportionPeriod": "2023-09-20T09:56:42",
    "ImportKPIs": [
        {
            "ImportKPI": "Sales",
            "MatchingKPI": {
                "KPIID": 2,
                "Name": "NetSales",
                "Description": "Sales",
                "Expression": "NetSales",
                "ReturnType": "System.Double",
                "NumberFormatID": 2,
                "Precision": 0,
                "CarryForward": false,
                "IsSummed": true,
                "IsApportioned": true,
                "IsTargetCalculated": false,
                "UsesQuarterRounding": false,
                "UseFlatApportioning": false
            },
            "KPIID": 2,
            "Description": "Sales",
            "uid": 0
        }
    ],
    "TargetsToImport": {
        "113": {
            "Targets": {
                "keys": [
                    "03/09/2023"
                ],
                "values": [
                    {
                        "TargetValues": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Sales"
                            ],
                            "values": [
                                19892
                            ],
                            "Sales": 19892
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "03/09/2023": {
                    "TargetValues": {
                        "keys": [
                            "Sales"
                        ],
                        "values": [
                            19892
                        ],
                        "Sales": 19892
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "keys": [
            "113"
        ],
        "values": [
            {
                "Targets": {
                    "keys": [
                        "03/09/2023"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "TargetValues": {
                                "keys": [
                                    "Sales"
                                ],
                                "values": [
                                    19892
                                ],
                                "Sales": 19892
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "03/09/2023": {
                        "TargetValues": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Sales"
                            ],
                            "values": [
                                19892
                            ],
                            "Sales": 19892
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "TotalDistributionValue": 0,
    "TotalWeeklyDistributionValue": 0
},
"importKPIs": "Sales,2",
"targetsToImport": "113|2023-09-03:Sales^19892!,;",
"selectedWeeks": null,
"selectedPeriod": "2023-09-20",
"ignoreClosedHoursForApportioning": false
```

}

Class Object -

```
    public class ProcessTargetsRequest
    {
        public Session session { get; set; }
        public TargetImports targetImports { get; set; }
        public string? importKPIs { get; set; }
        public string? targetsToImport { get; set; }
        public string? selectedWeeks { get; set; }
        public string? selectedPeriod { get; set; }
        public bool ignoreClosedHoursForApportioning { get; set; }
    }

   public class TargetImports 
{
      public TargetImportTypes importType { get; set; }
        public ApportioningTypes apportioningType { get; set; }
        public PeriodApportioningTypes periodApportioningType { get; set; }

        public List<ImportKPIValue> importKPIs { get; set; }

        public List<DateTime> selectedWeeks { get; set; }
        public List<DailyDistribution> customDistribution { get; set; }
        public List<WeeklyDistribution> customWeeklyDistribution { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, TargetImportRow> targetsToImport { get; set; }

        public double totalDistributionValue { get; set; }
}
```

Error  I got in TargetImportRow and class for that is following -

```
    public class TargetImportRow 
{
    public Dictionary<DateTime, ImportTargets> targets { get; set; }
}

public class ImportTargets
    {
        public Dictionary<string, double> targetValues {get;set;}
}
```

As you see dictionary key here is DateTime and JSON.NET doesn't like it I tried to write the converter but my dictionaries are nested so i didn't got any success.
Converter -

```
public class DictionaryConverter<TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Dictionary<TKey, TValue>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                {
                    // Parse the property name (string) as a DateTime
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(reader.Value.ToString(), out DateTime dateTimeKey))
                    {
                        TKey typedKey = (TKey)Convert.ChangeType(dateTimeKey, typeof(TKey));
                        reader.Read(); // Move to the property value
                        TValue value = serializer.Deserialize<TValue>(reader);
                        dictionary[typedKey] = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dictionary;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Implement serialization logic if needed
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Do anybody have this problem and found the solution, please help me

Comment: There's no date key in the JSON string. Dates in JSON [must be in ISO8601 form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7493.html#section-4.3). Worse, `targets` contains *different* objects for different keys. A string array for `keys`, an object array for `values` and another object for the localized string. You can't use a `Dictionary<string,TWhat>` to cover such different types, unless you use `Dictionary<string,object>` or `Dictionary<string,dynamic>`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos public Dictionary<DateTime, ImportTargets> targets { get; set; } have DateTime as key in dictionary which raise error during deserialization

Comment: That's not what the JSON string contains though. In the JSON string `targets` doesn't have dates at all. It has one key `keys` that's a `string[]`, a `values` that's `ImportTargets[]` and a *string* with a localized date literal that contains a single `ImportTargets`. Three different contents and *none* is a `Dictionary<DateTime,ImportTargets>`. If C# had discriminated unions you'd need a `Dictionary<string,string[] | ImportTargets | ImportTargets[]>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but the error i got is following - Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not convert string 'keys' to dictionary key type 'System.DateTime'. Create a TypeConverter to convert from the string to the key type object. Path 'targetImports.TargetsToImport.113.Targets.keys', line 1, position 661.

Comment: Exactly. The error said it can't parse the string whose value is `keys` as if it was a date. The code threw before it had a chance to try and convert `string[]` into an `ImportTargets` object, or tried to parse `values` as a date

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How can i change my convertor to solve it?

Comment: @JTouchLogic "Error I got in TargetImportRow and class" I am sorry but I  can not see any TargetImportRow. You have to post it if  you need some help

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the question as I missed that class

Comment: @Serge I update the question with proper class

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change your data structure a little. Instead of a Dictionary, add a DateTime property to your class. Otherwise your data will be very sloppy. Here is a relevant code

```
 var data=  JObject.Parse(json)["targetImports"]["TargetsToImport"]
                                                .ToObject<TargetsToImport>();

public class TargetsConverter : JsonConverter<Targets>
{
    public override Targets ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Targets existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var targets = jObj.ToObject<Targets>();

        foreach (var item in jObj.Properties())
        {
            if (item.Name == "keys" || item.Name == "values") continue;

            var dt = item.Value.ToObject<DT>();
            dt.DtKey = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Name);
            targets.Dt = dt;
        }
        return targets;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Targets value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

classes

```
public class DT
{
    public DateTime DtKey { get; set; }
    public TargetValues TargetValues { get; set; }
}

public class _113
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TargetsConverter))]
    public Targets Targets { get; set; }
}

public class Targets
{
    public List<string> keys { get; set; }
    public List<Value> values { get; set; }

    public DT Dt { get; set; }

}

public class TargetsToImport
{
    [JsonProperty("113")]
    public _113 _113 { get; set; }
    public List<string> keys { get; set; }
    public List<Value> values { get; set; }
}

public class TargetValues
{
    public List<string> keys { get; set; }
    public List<int> values { get; set; }
    public int Sales { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public TargetValues TargetValues { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TargetsConverter))]
    public Targets Targets { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @serge but the problem is I can't change it because code is migrated from ASP.net web services to Rest API and in web services there is no problem.

Comment: and ask him not to let to lost your job